# How to send email via terminal

Tags: macos, email, terminal

I have a script that I wrote that scrapes relevant information from an Excel file, creates a text file and then sends that to the recipient. A sort of homemade mail merge that I executed via terminal. The key command was something of the form:

```
curl --ssl-reqd 
     --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' 
     --user 'myemail@gmail.com:mysecretpassword' 
     --mail-from 'myemail@gmail.com' 
     --mail-rcpt 'myotheremail@work.com' 
     --upload-file 'filename.txt'
```

I got all this by working through questions and answers from here. It worked well but recently Gmail won't allow me to do this anymore. This is due to account security, two-factor authentification. My question is, how can I continue sending emails through the terminal? How do I modify the command above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since google deprecated Less secure apps, you'll have to use an "App Password" https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

P.S. This requires 2-factor authentication enabled for your google account.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did come across what you say, but I can't make sense of it. How does my original command above need to be modified to include the App Password?

Comment: @Geoff If it doesn't let you authenticate, replace "mysecretpassword" with your app password

Comment: This worked! To be precise I created an App Password for Terminal and replaced the password so generated into my script. Bingo! Great stuff. Many thanks.